# How do I combine AND and OR using Sequel?

Tags: sql, ruby, database, sequel

I want to generate a SQL query like the following using Ruby's Sequel:

```
SELECT * FROM Objects WHERE (color = "red" AND shape = "triangle") OR 
                            (color = "blue" AND shape = "square") OR
                            (color = "green" AND shape = "circle")
```

I want to build this query programmatically from a list of conditions, so that I can do something like this:

```
conditions = [[[:color, "red"], [:shape, "triangle"]],
              [[:color, "blue"], [:shape, "square"]],
              [[:color, "green"], [:shape, "circle"]]]
DB[:Users].where(conditions.sql_or)
```

It doesn't have to follow that exact form, but I want to be able to build the conditions programmatically, so it's not sufficient to be able to construct this query by hand.

Comment: *Generate a SQL query using SQL*... you just showed us a SQL query. Can you clarify your requirements?

Comment: @njk Replace the second "SQL" with "Ruby's Sequel". I've applied an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
conditions = [ 
               {:color => "red", :shape => "triangle"},
               {:color => "blue", :shape => "square"},
               {:color => "green", :shape => "circle"}
             ]

head, *tail = *conditions

tail.inject(DB[:Users].filter(head)){|mem,obj| mem.or(obj) }
```

I get:

```
=> #<Sequel::Postgres::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM \"Users\" WHERE (((\"color\" = 'red') AND (\"shape\" = 'triangle')) OR ((\"color\" = 'blue') AND (\"shape\" = 'square')) OR ((\"color\" = 'green') AND (\"shape\" = 'circle')))">
```

Comment: +1. It made my head hurt for a minute because I never considered using `inject` on a Sequel dataset but then it clicked. Nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will return an equivalent result, using a different SQL query:

```
DB[:Objects].where('(color, shape) in ?', conditions.sql_value_list).sql
=> "SELECT * FROM `Objects` WHERE ((color, shape) in (('red', 'triangle'), ('blue', 'square'), ('green', 'circle')))"
```

`sql_value_list` is documented in http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Array.html

Otherwise use:

```
objects = DB[:Objects].where(conditions[0])
conditions[1 .. -1].each { |c| objects = objects.or(c) }
```

Which results in:

```
SELECT * FROM `Objects` WHERE (((`color` = 'red') AND (`shape` = 'triangle')) OR ((`color` = 'blue') AND (`shape` = 'square')) OR ((`color` = 'green') AND (`shape` = 'circle')))
```

---

I was looking at Iain's answer, and it's basically the same as my second one, only more succinct; I like its elegance.